# Codeigniter routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter is it possible to make routing ignore a certain pattern but route everything else, for example I would like `tests/index` to be treated as normal but anything other than `/index`  I would like to routed through `tests/test` is this possible?

Comment: See [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive how well this will work, but try
It should match everything but index, and route it to the tests/whatever it matched.
`$routes["test\/((?!index).*)"] = 'tests/$1';`

Comment: I think the OP intends this: `'tests/test/$1';`